# Creating a Conda plugin

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

**Background**:

We have begun saving explicit environments (*conda list --explicit*) that we upload to a repository.

I've written a script that will build a conda environment based on one of those files (effectively *conda create -n foo --file url* with some helpers and sugar)

**Question:**

I can't find anything about how to create a conda submodule (*conda-build, conda-env, conda-script*).  I can pick it apart and figure it out, but if someone knew if there was process/best practice (like building Flask extensions) around doing this, it would be very helpful.

Does anyone know how to do this?  Is it simply dropping it into the executables directory via entry points in a setup.py script?